# Question about spectra in non-unital algebras

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a non-unital complex commutative Banach algebra. I am in the process of showing:

$$ \sigma (a) = \{\chi (a) \mid \chi \in \Omega (A) \} \cup \{0\}$$

where $\sigma$ denotes the spectrum and $\Omega (A)$ the characters. Let $\widetilde{A}$ denote the unitization of $A$.

> My first question is: shouldn't it be $ \sigma (a) = \{\chi (a) \mid
>  \chi \in \Omega (\color{red}{\widetilde{A}}) \} \cup \{0\}$? The
>   expression above is given in a text I'm reading but I think it's a
>   typo.

Anyway. Now for what I've done so far for the $\supseteq$ direction (and my question regarding that):

Note that $a-0=a$ is not invertible in $A$ because $A$ is not unital. Also,
$$ (b,\lambda)\cdot (a,0) = (ab+\lambda a , 0) = (a(b+\lambda),0)$$
hence $(a,0)$ is not invertible in $\widetilde{A}$. Hence $0\in \sigma(a)$.

Next the bit I'm stuck with:

Now consider $\chi (a)$. The goal is to show that $-(0,\chi (a)) + (a,0)=(a,-\chi (a))$ is not invertible in $\widetilde{A}$.Note that 
$$ (b,\lambda)\cdot (a,-\chi (a)) = (ab-b\chi (a) + a \lambda,-\lambda \chi (a))$$

which is equal to $(0,1)$ iff $\lambda = -\chi (a)^{-1}$ and $ab-b\chi (a) + \lambda a = 0$. If $\lambda = -\chi (a)^{-1}$ then $ab-b\chi (a) + \lambda a = ab -b\chi (a) -a\chi (a)^{-1}$.

> Now how can I show that $ab -b\chi (a) -a\chi (a)^{-1}\neq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: every character of $A$ extends uniquely to a character of $\tilde A$, so the distinction is irrelevant.

For your other question: the element $ab-b\chi(a)-a\chi(a)^{-1} $ is in $A$, which is not unital.

Note also that if  you apply $\chi$ to your candidate, you get $-1$.

Comment: Does your first sentence mean "Yes, you are right, it's a typo" or "No, you are wrong it is $\chi \in \Omega (A)$"?

Comment: I had not addressed that before. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now everything is so clear to me. I didn't realize that you hadn't addressed it and mistook your first sentence to be about the first part of my question.

Comment: You are welcome!